# Terminate with bad_alloc exception, but no "new" in stack trace

Tags: c++, linux, exception

C++ program is throwing this:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'St9bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc

Which it appears to be thrown from new, but the stack trace doesn't show any calls to new:

```
#0  0x0000003174a330c5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003174a34a76 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007f93b1b7b0b4 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler ()
at ../../../../gcc-4.3.4/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:98
#3  0x00007f93b1b794f6 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (handler=0x522b)
at ../../../../gcc-4.3.4/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:43
#4  0x00007f93b1b79523 in std::terminate ()
at ../../../../gcc-4.3.4/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:53
#5  0x00007f93b1b79536 in __cxxabiv1::__unexpected (handler=0x522b)
at ../../../../gcc-4.3.4/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:59
#6  0x00007f93b1b78ec8 in __cxxabiv1::__cxa_call_unexpected (exc_obj_in=0x7f93b1dae770)
at ../../../../gcc-4.3.4/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_personality.cc:750
#7  0x00007f93b2c356e0 in network::HttpLoader::doLoad (this=0x7f938801ef20) at loaders/HttpLoader.cxx:1071
#8  0x00007f93b2c70971 in network::Loader::load (this=0x522b) at Loader.cxx:899
#9  0x00007f93b2c74a15 in network::Loader::load2 (this=0x522b) at Loader.cxx:925
#10 0x00007f93b2c7b13a in network::LoaderThread::run() ()
#11 0x00007f93b1e60be4 in threads::Thread_startWorker (thr=0x7f938801e460) at Threads.cxx:479
#12 0x00007f93b1e60ead in threads::ThreadPool::run (this=0x1140478, thr=0x7f938801eeb0) at Threads.cxx:727
#13 0x00007f93b1e608e8 in threads::__Thread_startWorker (param=<value optimized out>) at Threads.cxx:520
#14 0x0000003175206ccb in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#15 0x0000003174ae0c2d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Added debugging statements at the beginning of doLoad(), but it never gets to that point.

Stumped!

Any thoughts?

Comment: could you post some of your code?

Comment: Have you looked at `loaders/HttpLoader.cxx:1071`?

Comment: `1070    Document* HttpLoader::doLoad()`
`1071         throw (Exception&)`   Pointing to the throw line, it never seems to get into the doLoad function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new` call may not be in the stack because it has already unwound at the point your application is terminating. I'd try to set a breakpoint at the moment the exception is *thrown* (e.g., using `catch throw` under gdb) -- at that point you'll see the cause of the exception in the stack.

Comment: Should have added this above, it doesn't throw the exception when ran in GDB, only in release build.

Comment: @Vireche: You can run a release build inside gdb, the type of build and whether you run it inside gdb are unrelated. Or do you mean that it only happens when not run from within gdb?

Comment: Yes it only happens when it is not ran in GDB, and only the release build demonstrates this problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.. Turns out it the new IT guy had set an exceptionally low value for the ulimit on memory (for my account).  So apparently it truly was running out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Maby the `new` call was inlined due to optimizations. Try to disable optimizations, at least in `loaders/HttpLoader.cxx`.